# Let python program on local machine know when server has changed a file on the server

Tags: php, python

I have a python program that sends an XML to my website when the user changes something on the local machine the python program is running on. I added some stuff on the website so the user can make the changes there and the python program will retrieve the XML file and make the changes on the local machine. The host I'm using for my website doesn't let me use php sockets. Right now I have the python program retrieving the XML file via FTP and checking if there is any change to the file.

I want to know if there's a way for the server to let the program know when it has changed the file or for the python program to detect the change without constantly retrieving the file and without sockets.

Comment: are php cronjobs allowed?

Comment: @Jeff, yes, but I think the shortest time allowed is every 10 mins. I don't want to wait that long to update the local machine. The way I have it right now updates within 1-2 seconds.